# Elasticsearch Java query with combination of AND/OR

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to write a query in Elasticsearch via Spring and Java (Elasticsearch client).

The query is somewhat like:

```
SELECT *** FROM elasticsearch_index 
WHERE isActive = 1 AND 
(
   (store_code = 41 AND store_genre IN ('01', '03') ) 
OR (store_code = 40 AND store_genre IN ('02') )
OR (store_code = 42 AND store_genre IN ('05', '06') )
)
AND LATITUDE ...  
AND LONGITUDE...
```

Please know that the parameters within the outer brackets is a `Map<Integer, String[]>`, so I would iterate over the `map` to add to AND + OR condition.

I tried with equivalent Java approach but does not seem to work:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("isActive", 1));

BoolQueryBuilder orQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (Entry<Integer, String[]> entry : cvsDepoMapping.entrySet()) {
  int key = entry.getKey();
  String[] value = entry.getValue();

  orQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("storeCode", key));    
  orQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("storeGenre", value)); // IN clause
  boolQueryBuilder.should(orQuery);
}
```

But neither is this working nor. I am certain of the solution.
I am struggling to find the Java equivalent conditions for the above condition.

I am using:

- Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE
- Elasticsearch 6.4.3

Comment: Are you able to construct the query in elasticsearch dsl?

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant I'm very new to elasticsearch, so as of now only tried with Java. I am not much confident on elasticseacrch DSL and how the condition would fit in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

within your or query you need to put a nested and query for each entry:

without trying to run it:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("isActive", 1));

BoolQueryBuilder orQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (Entry<Integer, String[]> entry : cvsDepoMapping.entrySet()) {

    BoolQueryBuilder storeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    int key = entry.getKey();
    String[] value = entry.getValue();
    storeQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("storeCode", key));
    storeQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("storeGenre", value)); // IN clause

    orQuery.should(storeQueryBuilder);
}
boolQueryBuilder.must(orQuery);
```

Comment: Hi, but I do not see any "should". Will it suffice for the requirement having OR?

Comment: oops, fixed that. I should not answer SO questions early in the morning. The storeQueryBuilders are added with should to the orQuery

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea and added it for myself and is giving results well. I'm verifying the query! Thank you for helping out!

Comment: great to hear. if it helped, please accept the answer

Comment: @AdiV apart from the answer given I would suggest you to understand how [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) works and how to [combine queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/bool-query.html).